# What would "Garth Brooks" refer to in a multiple-choice Poll?

Tags: slang, cultural-phrases

I noticed an online poll about marriage, where the person was curious to know what percentage of the current generation are interested in getting married, and the last option is: `Garth Brook`! I know this singer who has been too much on news these days for his canceled concert, and I also checked his *Personal Life* in Wikipedia out of curiosity, and still couldn't understand why he would be a poll item about marriage!

(P.S. Wikipedia says that he was married to someone and they later divorced, and that now he lives with someone else.)

This is the poll (the question and the options):

> Do you want to get married?
>
> 1. I want to get married (I’m male)
> 2. I want to get married (’m female)
> 3. I never want to marry (I’m male)
> 4. I never want to marry (I’m female)
> 5. Very unsure
> 6. I’m already married
> 7. Divorced
> 8. Garth Brooks

Comment: One might equally wonder why one's sex matters for items #1 through #4 and not for the rest, if and how #7 excludes #1 through #4, and why the verb for the first two is "get married" while that for the next two is "marry." One hypothesis covers all: the survey was designed by an idiot (or one of those typewriter monkeys).

Comment: Presumably it is an elliptical way of writing, “I want to marry Garth Brooks”. I mean, who wouldn’t?

Comment: I, @JanusBahsJacquet! xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In every survey, you will have people giving answers without any thinking. In this survey, they intentionally added a pointless answer that nobody would reasonably pick. The percentage of answers to this question gives you an estimate how many people have given pointless answers to any question. So if 1% check "Garth Brooks", you can reasonably estimate that each of the other seven questions also had 1% of responses due to people giving totally thoughtless answers. So of the people checking "divorced" one percent (of the total replies) are not saying the truth, they are not even lying, they gave you nonsense answers.

Answer (score 3):

"Garth Brooks" is a stand in for "I don't want to answer this question."
I'd've used "undecided" or "fuzzy kitties" myself, but the later might have attracted too many votes from people who actually have an opinion on the desirability of getting married.